# Base one datetime filter on another datetime filter in SSRS Report Builder

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, filter, report

I'm looking to either show an error message (fail) the report, if the end time filter is selected as being earlier than the start time filter, or disallow a user from selecting an end time that is before the currently selected start time.

Any ideas? I do not want to lose the pop up calendar functionality for the end time filter. I also don't want to set any kind of default value for the end time based on the start time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Error message is your option.

I looked into this earlier, I couldn't find much on it. Can't really restrict what user can pick unless you want to put valid available dates into a dropdown. If you want the datepicker(popup calendar) and you don't want to set a default for end date based on startdate, then just let the user pick, check if @EndDate < @StartDate either in you query or in an expression of the item you choose to display your message to the user.

Hope it helps